# how to generate sequence of string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

I want to generate a sequence of string from it, starting from length 1 until 5, for example:

```
0
1
2
...
x
y
z
00
01
02
...
zx
zy
zz
000
001
002
...
zzx
zzy
zzz
```

until 5 string length with the end will be zzzzz

my current code will only append to initial list of character, which will only create 2 character string

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

data=list("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

def addtostring(mystring):
  for y in data:
    output.append(mystring+y)

output=[]
for x in data:
  addtostring(x)

print output
```

I have to manually set the initial character, then append the end character

Need help to create a python script that will generate the list

Comment: So, you want to generate combinations? Check out `itertools.combinations`

Comment: @sytech: I think you'd want `itertools.product` here with a `repeat` argument, not `combinations`. And using `itertools.chain` will let you combine five separate `product` calls into a single generator.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're probably right. I just want OP to clarify what they're looking for exactly.

Comment: I added an example below how to use `itertools.product` for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with Python's default package **itertools.product**.

```
import itertools

chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

n = 2
for i in xrange(1, n+1):
    for item in itertools.product(chars, repeat=i):
        print "".join(item)
```

Where `n` is the max number of characters.

The output will look like this.

```
0
1
2
...
y
z
00
01
02
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a program that creates all length n strings if given a list of all length n-1 strings.

You currently use it to generate all length-2 strings from a list of the length-1 strings (`data`).

So you just need to make it a function, and call it for each of the remaining lengths you need, in order, passing it the strings of length 1 less.

The only (slight) complication is that you don't separate strings of different lengths, but that should be easy to handle.